# Why data is adding again and again in Loop on Firebase Database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying update form data into *Firebase Database*.

When i click on submit button, data is adding again and again in infinity loop on *Firebase Database*.

I can't find the error. I don't know what's going wrong with my code.

Anybody help me correcting the code.

```
LoginRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        long totalusers = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();

        final long userid = 100000 + totalusers;
        Random random = new Random();
        int n = random.nextInt();
        final String password = String.valueOf(userid).concat(String.valueOf(n));

        HashMap usermap = new HashMap();
        usermap.put("fullname", name);
        usermap.put("phonenumber", phoneNumber);
        usermap.put("sponsorid", sponsorId);
        usermap.put("emailid", emailId);
        usermap.put("userid", userid);
        UsersRef.child(String.valueOf(userid)).updateChildren(usermap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    HashMap loginmap = new HashMap();
                    loginmap.put("password", password);
                    LoginRef.child(String.valueOf(userid)).updateChildren(loginmap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                SendUserToUsersActivity();
                                Toast.makeText(AddUserActivity.this, "User Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } else {
                                String message = task.getException().getMessage();
                                Toast.makeText(AddUserActivity.this, "Error: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    String message = task.getException().getMessage();
                    Toast.makeText(AddUserActivity.this, "Error: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

I want the data to be added only once on Firebase Database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
 LoginRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
```

into this:

```
 LoginRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
```